# is this patent original?

Tags: patentability, prior-art-request, validity

In reference to the patent: [WO2016183695A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2016183695A1)

Hi. I am writing a report about pearls sooo the patent in reference claims a surgical procedure to culture abalone pearls in Chile. Yet I found this paper published 6 years earlier: Monteforte M. and Bervera H. 2010. Abalone pearl culture west coast of Baja California peninsula, Mexico. World Aquaculture 41(3):12-17. 
The paper describes practically the same claims. Thoroughly, in fact. Even the same species of abalone. How this patent got the registration ?

Comment: First, the linked document is an application, not a patent. Second, could you provide a link to the paper?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the link to the google patents page for this application you will see a box on the right that includes a "non-patent citation" link. If you go there you will see that there are seven references listed, three references are -

> MONTEFORTE, M. ET AL.: "Condiciones para el desarrollo de granjas perleras y producción de perlas: estado del arte, potencial y perspectivas.", REVISTA DE BIOLOGIA MARINA Y OCEANOGRAFIA, vol. 48, no. 1, 2013, pages 1 - 16, XP055330093 *
>
> MONTEFORTE, M. ET AL.: "III Foro Iberoamericano de los Recursos Marinos y la Acuicultura", 2011, article MONTEFORTE, M. ET AL.: "Tecnología de perlicultura en abulón.", pages: 199 - 208, XP055330079 *
>
> MONTEFORTE, M.: "Granjas perleras y perlicultura.", BIODIVERSITAS, vol. 89, 2010, pages 12 - 15, XP055330120, Retrieved from the Internet http://wvvw.biodiversidad.gob.mx/Biodiversitas/Articulos/biod iv89art3.pdf> [retrieved on 20160819] *

I think the various patent offices (AU, MX and Republic of Korea) now looking at this application know about the previous work.